# Concatenate a number to url everytime I click on the button?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, concatenation

How do I concatenate a number to string everytime I click on the button?
If I log cConcate variable you will see that the first value is right but on subsequent clicks the url refuses to update.

```
var tNumber = 1;
var sSting = "http://www.test.com/";
var cConcate = sSting + tNumber
$("button").click(function(){
    tNumber++;
    console.log(cConcate);
    console.log(tNumber);
});
```

Here is the online version:
http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/MwwRZG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `cConcate` inside `button click event` as it should get updated.
Change your code to

```
var tNumber = 1;
var sSting = "http://www.test.com/";
var cConcate = sSting;
$("button").click(function(){
  tNumber++;
  cConcate= cConcate + tNumber;
  console.log(cConcate);
  console.log(tNumber);
});
```

Or if you want to append only one number:

```
var tNumber = 1;
var sSting = "http://www.test.com/";
$("button").click(function(){
  tNumber++;
  var cConcate= sSting + tNumber;
  console.log(cConcate);
  console.log(tNumber);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the concatenation inside the click handler, instead of doing it only once:

```
var tNumber = 1;
var sString = "http://www.test.com/";
$("button").click(function(){
    var cConcate = sString + tNumber++;
    console.log(cConcate);
    console.log(tNumber);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,

```
    var tNumber = 1;
    var sSting = "http://www.test.com/";

    $("button").click(function(){
        var cConcate = sSting + tNumber
        console.log(cConcate);
        console.log(tNumber);
        tNumber++;
    });
```